# how to upadate field in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

my code are not working, maybe because of the where statement. please help me with what is wrong with this line of code.

query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tblceas_vote SET fldpassword= $three WHERE fldstudno =$login");
```

Comment: Are you sure about the values if the variables? They're not possibly empty?

Comment: By the way, learn about [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and password hashing (e.g. bcrypt).

Answer (score 2):

Quotes will probably help:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tblceas_vote SET fldpassword= '$three' WHERE fldstudno ='$login'");
```

Otherwise the proper way is to use escaping:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: don't use `l'arrosoir` as password

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes or escape the string:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tblceas_vote SET fldpassword='$three' WHERE fldstudno='$login'");
```

Or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tblceas_vote SET fldpassword='".$three."' WHERE fldstudno='".$login."'");
```

Also note that MYSQL is deprecated and you should use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  Quote are definitely required for text within queries.
Also I would suggest you "escape" you content (have a look at mysqli_real_escape_string).

If you ever encounter a "quote" inside your string, it will break your query, unless you escape it.